# Angular PrimeNG - set pTooltip dynamically from typescript

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to add tooltip to a `<div>` programmatically and that `<div>` is generated dynamically and I cant access HTML directly. I can able to get the `<div>` using `@HostListener` and I am setting the attribute, but it is not showing.

```
    @HostListener('mouseover', ['$event.target']) toolTipevent(e: any) {
        if(e.className == "my-class") {
            e.setAttribute('pTooltip', 'Select...'); // approach 1
            e.setAttribute('tooltip', 'Select...'); //approach 2
        }
    }
```

I tried both above approaches and the attribute is getting added to the particular `<div>` (can see the attribute in DOM) but not able to see the tooltip when hovering. Is there anything else specific to `primeng` I need to do? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You'll most likely need to (1) inject the `pTooltip` directive into the raw HTML and (2) compile an Angular component out of the result afterwards.

Comment: @skink, do you have any refence link, so that I can go through it?